# Using php preg_replace_callback - but replacing whole string not each sub string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Hi I hope someone can help, as not too hot on regular expressions.

Got a script snippet as follows..

```
<?php

$news="test message {image=abc} more text text text {image=def}";

$news=preg_replace_callback("/\{image=.*\}/i",function ($matches) { $field=$matches[0];  return "*".$field."*"; }, $news);


echo $news;

?>
```

However when i run it, it returns

```
test message *{image=abc} more text text text {image=def}*
```

Instead I want it to return..

```
test message *{image=abc}* more text text text *{image=def}*
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Like anubhava's answer - many thanks for replying.. I was so close, yet so far :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your regex `non-greedy` by using `.*?` instead of `.*`:

```
$news = "test message {image=abc} more text text text {image=def}";
$news = preg_replace_callback("/\{image=.*?\}/i",function ($matches) { 
                 return "*".$matches[0]."*"; }, $news);

echo $news;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
test message *{image=abc}* more text text text *{image=def}*
```

Answer (score 1):

Why callback?

```
$news = preg_replace("/(\{image=[^\}]+\})/i", "*$1*", $news);
```

Comment: Why do you use group 1 ? You could remove the parentheses and use `$0` in the replacement, anyways +1 :)

Comment: Day late and $1 short.